# Error in executing python scripts as modules with python -m option in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2to3

I am migrating my code from python2 to python3
and I am facing following issue with python3 -m command.

I have a python script which in some cases may be compiled(.pyc) or non-compiled(.py)
so I am not sure whether it is .py or .pyc
but I wanted to execute it

so in python2 if I had to execute that script I would simply do
`/usr/bin/python2 -m <path-to-script-without-extension>`

In above case I don't require to specify whether it is .py or .pyc

however in python3 if I do,
`/usr/bin/python3 -m <path-to-script-without-extension>`
I get
`/usr/bin/python3: No module named <path-to-script-without-extension>`

another way of executing python script is to do
`/usr/bin/python3 <path-to-script>`
but in order to get `<path-to-script>` I need to know whether the script ends with .py or .pyc

consider following example

```
root@geek:~# cat /tmp/script.py
#!/usr/bin/python3
print("Python script executed") # This syntax works for python2 as well as python3

root@geek:~# ls -l /tmp/script.py # Making sure the script is executable
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 100 Mar 19 05:49 /tmp/script.py

root@geek:~# /usr/bin/python2 -m /tmp/script # The syntax that used to work in python2
Python script executed

root@geek:~# /usr/bin/python3 -m /tmp/script # not working in python3
/usr/bin/python3: No module named /tmp/script

root@geek:~# env PYTHONPATH="/tmp" /usr/bin/python3 -m /tmp/script # Even tried setting PYTHONPATH but didn't work :(
/usr/bin/python3: No module named /tmp/script

root@geek:~# /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys; sys.path.append("/tmp");import script;' # Added path to sys.path, and it worked but looks more like a workaround
Python script executed
```

Is there a way to execute python script whose extension we don't know (it can be .py or .pyc)
Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe the problem may be that your `sys.path` variable needs to be updated to include the folder path(s) where you expect to find the `.py` file(s). It shouldn't matter if modules are compiled. I believe you can set PYTHONPATH to include these folders, and `sys.path` should have entries for them. Also you can dynamically append folder paths to `sys.path` at runtime.

Comment: Yes, in a nutshell, Python doesn't see your module in any of the paths it looks for, that's your only problem.

Comment: `PYTHONPATH=/tmp /usr/bin/python3 -m script` should work

Comment: Thanks  @Todd, deceze and rolf82, for your solutions.

Now I understood one major difference between python2 and python3 in terms of importing modules.
Even after updating PYTHONPATH, I was importing it in wrong way.
thanks for correcting me and helping me out.

Comment: in the shell, `export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/home/<username>/<modulefolder>` will update the variable.

Comment: you can also add that as a line to your `.profile` or `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Thanks @Todd,
I tried it out and it worked.
Thanks!